# Tradução de mensagem após edição de perguntas

Tags: bug, status-futuro, internacionalização

Agora a pouco, fiz uma edição em uma pergunta. Como não tenho reputação suficiente, ela fica na fila para que os que possuem esse privilégio aceitarem ou não.

[image: Texto após edição de pergunta]

> **Obrigado por sua edição!**
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

Mas, o retorno agora está em inglês. 
Tenho quase certeza que, das outras vezes, essa mensagem estava em Português.
Alguma coisa foi mudado?

Answer (score 9):

This message text is properly configured for our translation system and is awaiting manual translation. As soon as it is translated, it will appear correctly on the website. Sorry for the delay in this process. Alternatively, the moderators could ask Gabe to translate it manually ahead of the process.

> Esta mensagem está devidamente configurada para o nosso sistema de
>   tradução e está aguardando a tradução manual. Assim que for traduzida,
>   ela aparecerá corretamente no site. Desculpe pela demora neste
>   processo. Alternativamente, os moderadores poderiam pedir ao Gabe para
>   traduzi-la manualmente, adiantado assim o processo.

Comment: "This edit will be visible only to you until it is [peer reviewed]." -> "Esta edição ficará visível apenas para você até ela ser [revisada por pares]."

Answer (score 6):

Sugestão de tradução:

> Esta edição só será visivel para você até ser analisada pela comunidade.

Comment: "**por pela**"?

Comment: "para si" não funciona no Brasil.

Comment: @bfavaretto mudei para "para tí". Funciona melhor?

Comment: @Math pois... ontem estava cansado e a cabeça não deu para mais :) corrigí, obrigado.

Comment: "tí" não tem acento. Prefiro "só será visível para você". E a grafia correta é "analisada" e não "analizada".

Comment: @VictorStafusa bem visto, mudei.

Comment: Agora está perfeito para os brasileiros. Pra mim é a melhor tradução, mas achei que vocês portugueses não iriam gostar do "você" ;)